# function not appropriately defined within userform subroutine

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I apologize if this is a dumb question but I've been unable to find an answer to my current issue. I am attempting to create a userform which searches spreadsheet data based on input in the combobox for username, a start date, and an end date.

There is one user column and all other columns correspond to dates. The data is a daily workload productivity number (e.g., 87 widgets). The goal is to be able to enter inputs and copy the data from the raw data spreadsheet to a results spreadsheet, showing information for one user during that date range.

I keep getting an error ("Compile error: Sub or Function not defined") regarding my attempt to use the function to define columns for the appropriate dates. I'd appreciate any input. Thanks.

```
'Function changes column number to column name
Public Function fnColumnToLetter_CellAdressReplace(ByVal ColumnNumber As Integer)
fnColumnToLetter_CellAdressReplace = Replace(Replace(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "1", ""), "$", "")
End Function

Private Sub SearchButton1_Click()
'Dim variables
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim name1 As String
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
Dim STARTcol As String
Dim ENDcol As String
Dim pharmcol1 As String
Dim pharmcol2 As String
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set Results = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
'Variables for entries input into userform
name1 = userform1.NameBox1.Value
date1 = userform1.DateBox1.Value
date2 = userform1.DateBox2.Value

'Define row based on pharmacist name
rowno = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(name1, Range("A:A"), 0)
pharmrow = "a" + rowno

'Find first column from start date
STARTcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(date1, Range("A1:AZZ1"), 0)
'Find last column from end date
ENDcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(date2, Range("A1:AZZ1"), 0)

'Call function to replace column number to column name
pharmcol1 = fnColumnToLetter_CellAddressReplace(STARTcol) + rowno
pharmcol2 = fnColumnToLetter_CellAddressReplace(ENDcol) + rowno

'Copy table array to RESULTS worksheet
sheet.Range("pharmcol1:pharmcol2").Copy Destination = Results.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: What line is highlighted when the error happens?

Comment: Try `fnColumnToLetter_CellAddressReplace(STARTcol) & rowno`. The ampersand is the correct string concatenation operator.

Comment: you have a typo `fnColumnToLetter_CellAddressReplace` should be `fnColumnToLetter_CellAdressReplace`  The function only has one `d` in `Adress`

Comment: instead of calling a whole function that converts an address to a string just so Excel can turn it back into number why not" `sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(rowno,STARTcol),sheet.Cells(rowno,ENDcol).Copy...`

Answer (score 0):

## Compile error: Sub or Function not defined

Whenever I see this error I usually look for grammatical errors between the function/sub and the call.  In your case you have spelled Address differently between the two.

```
    Public Function fnColumnToLetter_CellAdressReplace(ByVal ColumnNumber As Integer)

    pharmcol1 = fnColumnToLetter_CellAddressReplace(STARTcol) + rowno
    pharmcol2 = fnColumnToLetter_CellAddressReplace(ENDcol) + rowno
```

Hope this helps.